# How do I connect to a 2nd database entered by parameter in the console? Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm entering by parameter in the console on behalf of the database to just do data import. The issue is that I can find the database but I can't connect to see its tables and extract some data.

*Database file*

```
        'searchDB' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => '',
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
            'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
            ]) : [],
        ],
```

*Comand file*

```
        $database = $this->argument('database'); //Name database old
        
        foreach (DB::select('SHOW DATABASES') as $db) {
            if($db->Database === $database){
                Config::set('database.connections.searchDB.database', $database); //NOT WORKING
                $tables = DB::select('SHOW TABLES')->connection('searchDB'); //NOT WORKING
                foreach($tables as $table) {
                    $tableNames[$database][] = $table;
                }
            }
        }
        dd($tables);//RETURNS THE CURRENT DATABASE.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supply the connection to the query builder **before** running a query

```php
$tables = DB::connection('searchDB')->select('SHOW TABLES'); // NOW WORKING
```

This is working for me

```php
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class StackOverflow extends Command
{
    /**
     * The name and signature of the console command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'overflow:stack {database}';

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'Command description';

    /**
     * Create a new command instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        $database = $this->argument('database'); //Name database old
        foreach (DB::select('SHOW DATABASES') as $db) {
            if ($db->Database === $database) {
                Config::set('database.connections.searchDB.database', $database); // Now Working
                $tables = DB::connection('searchDB')->select('SHOW TABLES'); // Now Working
                foreach ($tables as $table) {
                    $tableNames[$database][] = $table;
                }
            }
        }
        dd($tables); //RETURNS THE CURRENT DATABASE.
    }
}
```

[image]